# No known class method for selector while using PushNotificationIOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, react-native

I'm trying to get Push Notifications working in my React Native iOS app. I'm following the tutorial [PushNotificationsIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html). I have manually linked the Library as well.

[image: PushNotificationIOS Library]

In the AppDelegate.m file looks as follows,

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
 * of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
 */
#import "RCTPushNotificationManager.h"

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "RCTRootView.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

// Required to register for notifications
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
  [RCTPushNotificationManager didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}
// Required for the register event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
  [RCTPushNotificationManager didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
// Required for the notification event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification
{
  [RCTPushNotificationManager didReceiveRemoteNotification:notification];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  /**
   * Loading JavaScript code - uncomment the one you want.
   *
   * OPTION 1
   * Load from development server. Start the server from the repository root:
   *
   * $ npm start
   *
   * To run on device, change `localhost` to the IP address of your computer
   * (you can get this by typing `ifconfig` into the terminal and selecting the
   * `inet` value under `en0:`) and make sure your computer and iOS device are
   * on the same Wi-Fi network.
   */

  //jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://172.16.2.173:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];

  jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];

  /**
   * OPTION 2
   * Load from pre-bundled file on disk. The static bundle is automatically
   * generated by "Bundle React Native code and images" build step.
   */

  //jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"myapp"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

@end
```

But the build fails with the errors,

```
No known class method for selector 'didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:'
No known class method for selector 'didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:'
No known class method for selector 'didReceiveRemoteNotification:'
```

Why is this? How to fix this?

---

**PS: Note**

Found an alternative and it worked fine. [Apple Push Notification Services in iOS 6 Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

Comment: haev you want to use another tutorial?

Comment: @VvkAghera Please specify any if available.

Comment: follw my ans. in your code snippest i didn't find any issues. for more help ping me

Comment: @VvkAghera It did help me. Thank you. :)

Comment: @LukeDubert I updated the question with another tutorial. The AppDelegate code was altered.

Comment: @VvkAghera That script is in PHP, is there a Java example of it?

Answer (score 1):

please follow very easy and simple raywenderlich tutorial.
[APNS Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)
Hope this helps you.